# arduinoサンプルスケッチ「gnss_tracker」で測位情報取得について

Tags: spresense, arduino

Arduinoのサンプルスケッチ「gnss_tracker」で即位情報をすべて取得したいと
思ってソースを見ていますがGPGGAセンテンスのみ実装されていて他のセンテンスが
取得出来ません。
どのようにしたらよいか教えていただけないでしょうか。

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実は私も同じことを思っていました。
ご存じのとおり、このサンプルスケッチ「gnss_tracker」はgnss_nmea.cppの中で
GPGGAセンテンスの出力しか実装されていません。

その他のセンテンスを出力させるには、SDKで用意されているNMEA output libraryを
利用するのが手っ取り早いですが、これをArduinoで利用する方法が何故か公式情報では
提供されていません。

そんな中、ArduinoでNMEA output libraryを利用できるようにしたプログラム(スケッチ)を
公開されている方がいらっしゃるのでご紹介しておきます。
https://github.com/chibiegg/spresense-gnss-logger

Comment: ありがとうございました！大変有益な情報で、感謝しております。