# Arduino IDEを用いたQZQSM受信方法について

Tags: spresense

Arduino IDEでプログラミングし、spresenseを動かしています。
サンプルプログラムのおかげで、QZGSVの取得はできましたが、災危通報メッセージQZQSMが取得できません。
Arduino IDEでQZQSMを取得しようとすると、どのようなコードを書けばいいのでしょうか。
それとも、Arduino IDEでは、まだサポートされていないのでしょうか。
ご教授頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 関連する？質問:[SPRESENSE $QZQSMセンテンスの受信について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52991)

Comment: 対応したのは [Spresense SDK](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/release-notes/spresense-v1-2-1-release-2019-4-25) であって、Arduino IDE はまだのようですね。

Comment: ご助言ありがとうございます。早くArduino IDEでも対応になることを期待しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

別の質問(下記リンク)で回答させていただきましたが、NMEA output libraryをArduino IDEからも
利用できるようにしたプログラムが存在します。ただし、これもQZQSMセンテンスの出力には
対応しておらず、改造が必要です。
しかし、1からコードを書くよりは楽だと思うので、このプログラムを足がかりにして
改造方法を調べられてはいかがでしょうか。
完全な回答になっていなくてすみません。

[arduinoサンプルスケッチ「gnss_tracker」で測位情報取得について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57556/arduino%e3%82%b5%e3%83%b3%e3%83%97%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b9%e3%82%b1%e3%83%83%e3%83%81-gnss-tracker-%e3%81%a7%e6%b8%ac%e4%bd%8d%e6%83%85%e5%a0%b1%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)

Comment: ありがとうございます。プログラミング初心者の私には難しそうですが、チャレンジしたいと思います。

Comment: v1.4.0のリリースと同時に公式ドキュメントのサイトも一新され、そこにNMEA出力に対応したサンプルスケッチが掲載されました。これが使えると思われます。NMEA_SetMask(0x4000)のコメントを外せばQZQSMセンテンス出力も可能です。私もこれから試してみます。

Comment: 非常に有用な情報をありがとうございます。サイト見たら、親切になっていました。試してみたいと思います。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: 私のほうでサンプルスケッチを試してみましたが、残念ながらQZQSMだけが出力されません。NMEA_SetMask(0x40FF)と設定し、Gnss.select(QZ_L1S)もコメントアウトしましたが、それでもダメでした。まだどこかで追記修正が必要なようです。

Comment: 私も試してみましたが、出力されませんでした。0x4000も0x4000efなど、いろいろ変えてみましたが、ダメでした。

Comment: NMEA_DcReport_Output()関数を使う必要があることまではわかりました。もう少し手を入れないとQZQSMは出せないようです。

Comment: ドキュメントが更新されてますね。<https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_qzss_災危通報を出力する> まだArduinoで正式対応してないっぽいですが、ドキュメントの通りやれば出力できました

Comment: 私のところでもQZQSMの出力を確認しました。結局はライブラリが未対応というオチであったのと、ドキュメントに事実でないことが書かれていたという不整合さに振り回された形です。公式からの反応も未だにありませんね。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

Arduino環境でもQZQSMの受信をしたいというリクエストにお応えして次回バージョンアップで正式に対応します。
先行して試したいという方のために、現行バージョンに一部実装を追加して実現する方法をドキュメントに掲載しました。
[QZSS 災危通報を出力する](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_qzss_%E7%81%BD%E5%8D%B1%E9%80%9A%E5%A0%B1%E3%82%92%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

また、APIリファレンスのビットアサイン表記に誤りがありご迷惑をお掛けしました。
こちらの表が正しいビットアサイン(`$QZQSM`は`Bit14`)です。
[NMEA マスク値について](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_nmea_%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E5%80%A4%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
こちらご指摘頂くまで気が付いておりませんでした。こちらも合わせて修正致します。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: v1.4.1がリリースされていました。これでサイトのサンプルプログラムを記述すれば、QZQSMが出力できると思い、試してみましたが、何も出力されませんでした。 他に必要な設定があるのでしょうか？configファイルなど。 それとも、単にみちびきから信号が来ていなかっただけなのでしょうか？ サイトのサンプルプログラムで動作した方がいらっしゃいましたら、いろいろ教えていただけましたら、うれしいです。

Comment: 受信できました。（条件：窓内側、曇り空）前回は、みちびきからの信号をキャッチできていなかったようです。
設置角度が効いているのかもしれません。

Comment: シリアルモニターに表示されるメッセージ（9AA・・・A24）をプログラム内で判別しようとしたのですが、これをStringやcharで取得する方法が分かりません。Stringで取得するように書いてみると、78が得られました。どなたかご存知の方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。
表示例
$QZQSM,56,9AADF53C5680050C8AA1F5543ED2880C51022A2EF554E22AA0000012335EA24*7D

Answer (score 0):

関連する部分だったのでこちらで質問させていただきます。

v1.4.0のドキュメント
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/api-reference/api-references-spresense-sdk/group__gnss__nmea.html

NMEA_SetMaskのMask descriptionにbit22：QZQSMとあります。
これは22ビット目に1を立る、つまり0x400000という理解ですよね？

サンプルスケッチでは
NMEA_SetMask(0x4000); // only QZQSM

となっていて何か違うような気が。。。
実際に0x4000と0x400000の両方で試しましたがデータとして拾えなかったのでわかりませんでした。

サンプルスケッチとドキュメント、どちらが正解なのでしょうか？
とぼけた質問でしたら大変申し訳ありません。

Comment: 私の記憶違いでなければ、前バージョンv1.3.1までは14ビット目になっていたと思います。SDK側のドキュメントにその痕跡があります。APIリファレンスの記載どおり22ビット目に変更されているとするなら、0x400000で良さそうな感じですが、それでも出てこないのは謎ですね。実機がいま手元に無くて試せないのですが。

Comment: ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当から出来れば正確な実装情報をいただきたいところですね。